# Subversion (Eclipse/Flash Builder) - After Team>Update to HEAD - where does one view what was updated?

Tags: eclipse, svn, flash-builder, subclipse

Subversion (Eclipse/Flash Builder) - After Team>Update to HEAD - where do you view what was updated?

I persume there is a log or something. I remember seeing the output of the Update in the console window once, but recently when looking for it, can seem to see any update info

Brian

**Update:** Answered below, just for others to see where, see screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show View *Console* ⇒ Press Toolbar Button *Open Console* ⇒ Choose *SVN Console*